# Reseting a multiplayer scene in UNET, without losing connections

Tags: unity, unet

I have a game with only one scene, which has the basic Network Manager HUD.

After I click "Host", and a few players join **one by one**, I want to **restart the scene**, so the **early joiners won't have advantage**.

Specifically: I want to reset the scene so it's in the **"server was just started* " state**, **every player is connected** and **their gameobjects have just spawned on the spawn location**.

I tried this line, but it **fully restarts** the scene, and even worse, now the **HUD won't even pop up**:

- `NetworkManager.singleton.ServerChangeScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);`

**Is there a simpler way than manually resetting everything to a hardcoded initial state?**

(*the state in which the scene is after I click "Host")

Comment: Just a heads up, UNet is being deprecated and will no longer work starting Spring 2022. https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001252086-UNet-Deprecation-FAQ I'd suggest looking into other multiplayer solutions. If you've already got everything set up in this one and are just doing finishing touches then it'll be fine to stick with it for now but if you're early in development or when you're starting a new project I'd recommend you avoid it.

Comment: I know that, and for this reason I'm trying to avoid any serious networking stuff, till the new networking comes to the stable versions. I'm just implementing the must-have, quick stuff for prototyping. But thanks for warning :)

Comment: Cool, as long as you know. Just didn't want you making everything with UNet and then it stops working on you.